# Clone a remote git repository using ssh

Tags: git, ssh

Hi I have a URL  ssh://your login @ computer name / location.

How do a clone this repository to `D:\MyRepo`

I'm not sure how to use it with ssh.

Comment: Just copy it with scp or rsync (you may have to install it first).

Answer (score 0):

By command line, use either `git clone user@server:/absolute/path/to/repo D:\MyRepo` or `git clone user@server:relative/to/homedir/repo D:\MyRepo`.

If you use a graphical tools like tortoiseSVN or something, the remote url you have to type in the appropriate field is something like `user@server:relative/to/homedir/repo`.

Answer (score -1):

If `git` is in `your_login` account `$PATH` on the server '`computername`':

git clone ssh://your_login@computer_name/location/of/git/repo

If you haven't added your public key to `~/your_login/.ssh/authorized_keys`, ssh will ask for your account password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I use the command I get  " Cloning into '<location>'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. "

Comment: @ImCoder when you are logged on `computername`, can you use git locally to clone the repo (locally, just for testing)?

Comment: Yes, I can. Even tried using Collabnet GitEye to clone the repo but similar error occurs

Comment: @ImCoder can you do a `ssh your_login@computer_name ls -alrt location/of/git/repo`? Do you see a `.git`?

Comment: When I directly ssh in the computer_name and go to that specific repository, I see all the files. However, when on my local machine i try to git clone ssh://<your_login>@computer_name <local directory>, I get the error                                                                                                                                               I guess it is something to do with my authorized keys, I need to set my login, computername and password in the authorized keys

Comment: @ImCoder but would a `ssh your_login@computer_name ls -alrt location/of/git/repo` work? Would the output include a `.git` folder?

Comment: It asks me for my Password, I enter it and then i can see folder containing .git

Comment: @ImCoder and what about `ssh your_login@computer_name which git`? (to check that `git` is in your `$PATH`)

Comment: Could not chdir to home directory /home/login: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/git

Comment: @ImCoder strange: it is like yourlogin has no homedir (http://serverfault.com/a/588250/783)

Comment: I have set an environment variable as Git_HOME and set it in the path variable however when i say echo it only displayes this /usr/bin. I have set
GIT_HOME=C:\Git  and PATH=$PATH;%GIT_HOME%/bin;

Comment: @ImCoder the $PATH on `computer_name` matters too: what `ssh your_login@computer_name ssh -c 'echo $PATH'` returns?

Comment: First it asked me for my password, then gave this message - Could not chdir to home directory /home/your_login: No such file or directory
Unknown cipher type 'echo'

Comment: @ImCoder that might be your issue right there: make sure the account exists on the server side.